# PayPal partial parallel payment: Three payments OK, one errored with “The Buyer returned without completing the payment. (13114)”

Tags: paypal

Basically, how is this kind of a scenario possible?

One payment (of four) of a single transaction failed as `returned without completing` although three other payments of the same transaction were completed allright. Overall transaction status is `PaymentActionCompleted`.

How can user “return without completing” for just one payment? I suppose this must be some timing issue? I know that the parallel payments aren't transacted, but I was under impression that at least the commitment (clicking “Pay Now”) would be atomic, and that — for example — clicking cancel right after commit would do little.

To repeat the error message (for the single failed payment): `The Buyer returned without completing the payment. (13114)`.

I've seen lots of “partial successes” with other error messages, but this is the first message that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Janne, can you provide the correlation id you received in the response?

Comment: Hi Dennis, the latest response was `7ee71b2ab5f8c`

Comment: was that Express Checkout or Adaptive Payments. Was it on live or sandbox?

Comment: Express Checkout (if I'm identifying those correctly), live.

Comment: I've had a few similar cases processing payments on freedomsponsors.org